# marmalade mkb send user defined parameter

Tags: marmalade

I am using MKB to develop an app for ios and android.

I need to send a user define parameter/symbol that I can conditionally set other stuff in the MKB.

Currently only assets and deployments can be "platformized" by deployargs.

but I would like to define a symbol based on if it is iOS or android.

and then use that symbol within the MKB file itself.

e.g. how do i set ios or android from the command line

```
if {{ defined ios }} {
    message "iOS defined"
}
elif {{ defined android }}
    message "android defined"
else {
    message "nothing was defined"
}
```

Comment: This is not generally supported because, in the normal process, the same marmalade binaries are used for both iOS and Android. Instead you should enquire at run-time.

Comment: yes usually the normal process is to have the same binaries. But i have a scenario when i need to have this check